# Can we download Cloud Functions from cloud shell or gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

Can we download Cloud Functions from cloud shell or gcloud ? At the moment we have the option to download from UI in the source tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, the GUI action required a cookies for the authentication and you can't pass an access token or a identity token.

You can't perform this action programmatically (or with a lot of effort, and with a personal authentication. I think that service account won't be able to do this)